# designing classes for other developers to use in java

Tags: java

```
class CSVReader  {

private List<String> output;
private InputStream input; 

public CSVReader(InputStream input) {
this.input = input;
}

public void read() throws Exception{
  //do something with the inputstream
  // create output list.
}

public List<String> getOutput() {
return Collections.unmodifiableList(output);
}
```

I am trying to create a simple class which will be part of a library. I would like to create code that satisfies the following conditions:

- handles all potential errors or wraps them into library errors and
  throws them.
- creates meaningful and complete object states (no incomplete object structures).
- easy to utilize by developers using the library

Now, when I evaluated the code above, against the goals, I realized that I failed badly. A developer using this code would have to write something like this -

```
CSVReader reader = new CVSReader(new FileInputStream("test.csv");
reader.read();
read.getOutput();
```

I see the following issues straight away - 
- developer has to call read first before getOutput. There is no way for him to know this intuitively and this is probably bad design.

So, I decided to fix the code and write something like this

```
public List<String> getOutput() throws IOException{
if(output==null) 
   read();
return Collections.unmodifiableList(output);
}
```

OR this

```
public List<String> getOutput() {
if(output==null) 
   throw new IncompleteStateException("invoke read before getoutput()");
return Collections.unmodifiableList(output);
}
```

OR this

```
public CSVReader(InputStream input) {
read(); //throw runtime exception
}
```

OR this

```
public List<String> read() throws IOException {
//read and create output list.
// return list
}
```

What is a good way to achieve my goals? Should the object state be always well defined? - there is never a state where "output" is not defined, so I should create the output as part of constructor? Or should the class ensure that a created instance is always valid, by calling "read" whenever it finds that "output" is not defined and just throw a runtime exception? What is a good approach/ best practice here?

Answer (score 2):

I would make `read()` private and have `getOutput()` call it as an implementation detail. If the point of exposing `read()` is to lazy-load the file, you can do that with exposing `getOutput` only

```
public List<String> getOutput() {
   if (output == null) { 
      try {
        output = read();
      } catch (IOException) {
        //here you either wrap into your own exception and then declare it in the signature of getOutput, or just not catch it and make getOutput `throws IOException`
      }
   }
   return Collections.unmodifiableList(output);
}
```

The advantage of this is that the interface of your class is very trivial: you give me an input (via constructor) I give you an output (via getOutput), no magic order of calls while preserving lazy-loading which is nice if the file is big.

Another advantage of removing `read` from the public API is that you can go from lazy-loading to eager-loading and viceversa without affecting your clients. If you expose `read` you have to account for it being called in all possible states of your object (before it's loaded, while it's already running, after it already loaded). In short, always expose the least possible

So to address your specific questions:

1. Yes, the object state should always be well-defined. Your point of not knowing that an external call on `read` by the client class is needed is indeed a design smell
2. Yes, you could call `read` in the constructor and eagerly load everything upfront. Deciding to lazy-load or not is an implementation detail dependent on your context, it should not matter to a client of your class
3. Throwing an exception if `read` has not been called puts again the burden to calling things in the right, implicit order on the client, which is unnecessary due to your comment that output is never really undefined so the implementation itself can make the risk-free decision of when to call `read`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make your class as small as possible, dropping the `getOutput()` method all together.

The idea is to have a class that reads a CSV file and returns a list, representing the result. To achieve this, you can expose a single `read()` method, that will return a `List<String>`.

Something like:

```
public class CSVReader {

    private final InputStream input;

    public CSVReader(String filename) {
        this.input = new FileInputStream(filename);
    }

    public List<String> read() {
        // perform the actual reading here
    }
}
```

You have a well defined class, a small interface to maintain and the instances of `CSVReader` are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first approach takes away some flexibility from the API: before the change the user could call `read()` in a context where an exception is expected, and then call `getOutput()` exception-free as many times as he pleases. Your change forces the user to catch a checked exception in contexts where it wasn't necessary before.
2. The second approach is how it should have been done in the first place: since calling `read()` is a prerequisite of calling `getOutput()`, it is a responsibility of your class to "catch" your users when they "forget" to make a call to `read()`.
3. The third approach hides `IOException`, which may be a legitimate exception to catch. There is no way to let the user know if the exception is going to be thrown or not, which is a bad practice when designing runtime exceptions.

The root cause of your problem is that the class has two orthogonal responsibilities:

- Reading a CSV, and
- Storing the result of a read for later use.

If you separate these two responsibilities from each other, you would end up with a cleaner design, in which the users would have no confusion over what they must call, and in what order:

```
interface CSVData {
    List<String> getOutput();
}
class CSVReader {
    public static CSVData read(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could combine the two into a single class with a factory method:

```
class CSVData {
    private CSVData() { // No user instantiation
    }
    // Getting data is exception-free
    public List<String> getOutput() {
        ...
    }
    // Creating instances requires a factory call
    public static CSVData read(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `getOutput` check if it is null (or out of date) and load it in automatically if it is. This allows for a user of your class to not have to care about internal state of the class's file management.

However, you may also want to expose a `read` function so that the user can chose to load in the file when it is convenient. If you make the class for a concurrent environment, I would recommend doing so.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph but not the second. You can also choose to load when it is convenient just by calling `getOutput` when it is convenient. See my answer for more details

Comment: I do tend to agree with your answer. It depends whether your needs depend on separating loading and reading within the same object, but that could just be implemented as a wrapper for additional functionality. Although I admit the use cases for this would be slim. Thank you for the feedback.